# row data to column data

Tags: pandas, csv

I am a newbie in python. I have data looks like this:

```
ID      Annotation  X   Y
ID_1    first       767 942
ID_1    last        768 943
ID_2    first       769 944
ID_2    last        770 945
```

I want to make new column first XY and last for XY. my expected result:

```
ID      X_first     Y_first     X_last      Y_last
ID_1    767         942         768         943
ID_2    769         944         770         945
```

thank you for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using `unstack` for the `pivot` problem

```
s=df.set_index(['ID','Annotation']).unstack()
s.columns=s.columns.map('_'.join) # columns flatten
s.reset_index(inplace=True)
s
Out[353]: 
     ID  X_first  X_last  Y_first  Y_last
0  ID_1      767     768      942     943
1  ID_2      769     770      944     945
```